# What can be said about the convergence of $\sum \frac {a_n}{a_nn^p+1} \text {?} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\sum a_n $ is a divergent series of real numbers.

What can be said about the convergence of $$\sum \frac {a_n}{a_nn^p+1} \hspace {15pt}\text {?} $$

Here $p \in \mathbb {R} $ is unspecified, meaning that different values may lead to different solutions.

---

*Note*.
This question (which comes from me, not a teacher) generalizes an exercise from Rudin.  Though the exercise in Rudin (which I solved prior to asking this question) keeps $a_n $ non-negative, I would like to know what happens if this assumption is dropped, in addition to taking arbitrary $p $. I do appreciate the very good answers below for the non-negative case; however, this is why I have not yet accepted an answer.

I did not give my progress because I had not made any. I am asking a question about mathematical analysis, not requesting homework help.

Comment: What have you found out about $$\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n n^p + 1}$$ so far?

Comment: It might be easier to think of the term in the following, equivalent form (if no $a_n$ is $0$) $$\frac{1}{n^p+\frac1{a_n}}$$

Comment: Sorry, Mhenni Benghorbal, I wrote a comment which was false. If that was why you deleted your answer, please undelete it.

Comment: Uh, are all $a_n > 0$? Or do we have some nonpostive terms?

Comment: Please reopen this question. It should never have been closed. The context you claim is missing is clearly evident from the content of the question. Furthermore, this is a useful question (with a good, but still incomplete, set of answers) that will continue to be helpful to future users.

Comment: Moreover, to the closers, please read carefully before deciding someone is simply asking for homework help (which I am not), much less trying to cheat. This witch hunt against homework has become overzealous and is shutting out legitimate questions.

Comment: Sometimes I ask the obligatory "What have you done so far?" question because I think that someone might just be looking for an answer to a homework question.  That wasn't the case here!  I could tell that this was more of a generalizing curiosity that you had, not a homework problem.  I was only looking to piggy-back off any work that you did and see if you were only interested in the $a_n > 0$ case.  Now I know the answer to the latter, so I'll see what I can find out about the general $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  We assume that $a_n > 0$, in keeping with the exercise in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" that seemed to inspire this question, namely Exercise 3.11(d).  This question is a generalization of that exercise, in which $p = 1$ and $p = 2$ were the only two cases considered.

Note that,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_n n^p + 1} & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p + \frac{1}{a_n}} \\
& \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}.
\end{align*}
We have that $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges if $p > 1$ and diverges if $p \leq 1$ by the following.  If $p \leq 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^p} \neq 0$ for $p \leq 0$, hence $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ diverges.  If $p > 0$, then we can use a theorem of Cauchy to get us to the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k \cdot \frac{1}{2^{kp}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{(1-p)k}.$$  Given that $2^{1-p} < 1$ if and only if $1 - p < 0$, we have that $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for $p > 1$ by comparison with the geometric series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2^{1-p})^n = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-p}}.$$

Therefore, we have that $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n n^p + 1}$ converges if $p > 1$.

Let $p \leq 1$.  Suppose that we let $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.  Then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^p a_n + 1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{n^p \frac{1}{n} + 1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p + n} \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n},$$ which diverges.

We therefore have that $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n n^p + 1}$ converges for any $a_n > 0$ if $p > 1$ and we can choose some $a_n > 0$ such that $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n n^p + 1}$ diverges for all $p \leq 1$.

Comment: $a_n > 0$ is not obligatory. With $a_n = (-1)^n$,  we have $\sum_n a_n$ diverging. I imagine that $a_n = sin(n)$ has the property

Comment: If we do not have that $a_n > 0$, then this problem seems to get less interesting.  I assumed that $a_n > 0$ since this problem is a generalization of a popular exercise in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", Exercise 3.11(d), where $a_n > 0$ is given.  But if you want to turn the conversation to any such real, divergent series $\sum a_n$, I suppose that it could end up being interesting!  Definitely not as clean though.

Comment: I'll add a note to the beginning of my answer to let people know that I'm assuming that $a_n > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one observation if $a_n > 0 $, $\sum_{n} a_n $ diverges and $p>1$ then the series

> $$ \sum \frac {a_n}{a_nn^p+1} $$

converge.

Comment: I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @Regret: It is ok. Thanks for the comment.